# jQuery setTimeout delay for an element

Tags: jquery

Is there an easier way to wait for an element to load ( by independant script/mootools/other ). For example:

I am waiting for a google map to load, but I don't want to use its API for checks. So I made two functions:

```
function checkIfexist() {
    if(jQuery('#container').length)
        return 0;
    else
        reload(1);
}

function reload(mode) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        do stuff
            .
            .
            .
        if(mode==1)
            checkIfexist();
    }, 400);
}
```

I am starting it with `reload(1);` Is there an easier way to use setTimeout in such a way? I don't want to use delay, wait or whatever.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the Google Map API to check for map loaded completion?

Comment: Because this is not only for Google Map API, it is for all kind of AJAX requests, also done by otside site scripts. Best way is to use setTimeout and check after some time if it is loaded or not. Sometimes jQuery function doesn't give good results against foreign APIs for DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) fires when all concurrent ajax requests have finished, so you can just use it directly, for example:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        // all ajax is done
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you :) this works for jQuery though. What if we used javascript/mootools to inject elements after page load?